# How to swap ctrl and caps lock using xmodmap

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-10.10, capslock, xmodmap

Or any other tool, but I prefer xmodmap.
I tried this:

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```

I also tried this:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Control_L"
```

But neither seem to fully work. Here's the event log for pressing caps lock:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x1a00001,
root 0x12d, subw 0x0, time 914826, (679,342), root:(680,362),
state 0x12, keycode 66 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37 // 37 is the control key code
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with awesome window manager.

Comment: I'd try to directly map keycodes to intended behavior. For example, I like to bind my caps lock key as additional shift and hide the normal caps lock behavior behind shift (so to enable/disable caps lock on my keyboard shift+caps lock is required): `xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Shift_L Caps_Lock"`.

Comment: Regarding "other tools" see also [linux - Remap keys without xmodmap or any X tools - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/729585/remap-keys-without-xmodmap-or-any-x-tools). I think it's more reliable because it works with some "lower-level" applications while using X does not work with e.g. anydesk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [Remap Caps Lock](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RemapCapsLock) :

> man xmodmap shows how to swap the left
>   control key and the CapsLock key:
>
> ```
> !
> ! Swap Caps_Lock and Control_L
> !
> remove Lock = Caps_Lock
> remove Control = Control_L
> keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
> keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
> add Lock = Caps_Lock
> add Control = Control_L
> ```

Comment: Uhm, that's my first attempt in my post.

Comment: Oups, missed that. Then why did it work this time?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think I forgot to reset the keymap after meddling with keycodes.

Answer (score 15):

This may work for you.

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"
```

Comment: How can I swap it back by setxbmap

Answer (score 1):

Swap:

```
setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"
```

Reverse the swap:

```
setxkbmap -option
```

Reference: [please click here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445099/whats-the-opposite-of-setxkbmap-option-ctrlnocaps)